# Looping through a list of names of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, formatting

I have a list of dataframes, each created from a unique web query;

```
bngimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419524'), None)
belimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419525'), None)
braimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419635'), None)
chilimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419526'), None)
chinimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419527'), None)
domimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419633'), None)
fraimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419636'), None)
greimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419528'), None)
ghaimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419638'), None)
indimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419530'), None)
indoimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419639'), None)
itaimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419533'), None)
japimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419534'), None)
kuwimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419640'), None)
litimp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419641'), None)
meximp = parse_forecast_data(get_json('419537'), None)
```

I need to format each dataframe in the same way as follows;

```
bngimp = bngimp[['From Date','Sales Volume']]
bngimp = bngimp.set_index('From Date')
bngimp.index = pd.to_datetime(bngimp.index)
bngimp = bngimp.groupby(by=[bngimp.index.year, bngimp.index.month]).sum()
bngimp.columns = ['bngimp']
```

Is there any way I could loop through the name of dataframes without having to copy and paste each dataframe name into the above code?

There will be multiple more dataframes so the copying and pasting quite time consuming!

Any help is much appreciated;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest create dictionary for map numbers by DataFrame names and create dictionary of `DataFrame` called `out`:

```
d = {'419524': 'bngimp', '419525': 'belimp', ...}

out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    df = parse_forecast_data(get_json(k), None)
    df = df[['From Date','Sales Volume']]
    df = df.set_index('From Date')
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    df = df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum()
    df.columns = [v]
    out[v] = df
```

then for get DataFrame select by key:

```
print (out['bngimp'])
```

Also if want create one big DataFrame is possible use:

```
df = pd.concat(out, axis=1)
```